# Server requirements for MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, system-requirements

I am attempting to get MVC2 installed on a server at work, and am being told they are required to install the `Visual Studio 2008 Package` in order for us to use it. Where I work this causes issues because we need tons of approvals etc. However the only thing I am finding anywhere I search is that the server requires .NET 3.5 sp1, which is currently on the server. The only thing I can think of is they are saying they need some sort of 2008 redistributable, or they are making the assumption that the actually *need* VS2008 on the server itself.

Anyway I have never installed MVC on a server before, and really just want to know if they dont understand the requirements or if I am overlooking something.

Comment: What version of IIS is the server running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC 2 is [bin-deployable](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/07/13/server-installation-options-for-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx), so you don't actually need to install it.

Comment: Really, so I could just include it with my app and not have to go through all of this to begin with? Hmm that might be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install anything on the server.

As long as the server has IIS with ASP.Net enabled and .Net 3.5 installed, MVC applications will work.

You just need to copy System.Web.Mvc.dll to the `bin` folder in your web application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're trying to run in IIS. 
Perhaps this post about registering the .net framework with iis would be useful:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(v=VS.90).aspx
And obviously switch on the required settings in IIS Manager.